# ¿Cómo envió estos datos del formulario validados por php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

actualmente tengo este formulario en html, php y js, con cual valido todo el formulario y necesito poder hacer que la url amigable 'compra' reciba estos datos, como puedo redireccionar a aquella url con los datos?.

```html
<section class="container_form">
  <div class="form">
    <h2>Rellena el formulario para participar</h2>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <?php if ($status_nombres == 'False'): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <?php echo $mensaje_nombres; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($status_apellidos == 'False'): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <?php echo $mensaje_apellidos; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($status_telefono == 'False'): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <?php echo $mensaje_telefono; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($status_email == 'False'): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <?php echo $mensaje_email; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($status_reemail == 'False'): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <?php echo $mensaje_reemail; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="nombres">Nombres</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres" id="" placeholder="Nombres" value="<?php if($status_nombres == 'True' && isset($nombres)) echo $nombres?>">
        <!--<div class="valid-feedback">Valido.</div>-->

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php if($status_apellidos == 'True' && isset($apellidos)) echo $apellidos?>">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rut">Rut</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut" id="rut" required oninput="checkRut(this)" placeholder="11111111-1" value="<?php if($status_rut == 'True' && isset($rut)) echo $rut?>">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="celular">Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="985114418" value="<?php if($status_telefono == 'True' && isset($telefono)) echo $telefono?>">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="correo">Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="" placeholder="example@gmail.com" value="<?php if($status_email == 'True' && isset($email)) echo $email?>">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recorreo">Repetir Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="reemail" class="form-control" name="reemail" id="" placeholder="example@gmail.com" value="<?php if($status_reemail == 'True' && isset($reemail)) echo $reemail?>">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="terminos" value="ok" id="customCheck" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck"><a href="">Acepto los términos y condiciones de las bases del concurso.</a> </label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit_compra" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">PAGA AQUÍ</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Después tenemos la validación la mayoria del formulario esta validado en php en este valido los nombres, apellidos, telefono, correo.

````
```
if(isset($_POST['submit_compra'])) {
    $nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $rut = $_POST['rut'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $reemail = $_POST['reemail'];
    $terminos = $_POST['terminos'];

    print_r($_POST);
    //validando nombres
    if(!empty($nombres)) {
        $nombres = htmlspecialchars($nombres);
        if(preg_match($patron_texto, $nombres)) {
            $status_nombres = 'True';
        } else {
            $mensaje_nombres = "El nombre sólo puede contener letras y espacios";
            $status_nombres = 'False';
        }
    } else {
        $mensaje_nombres = "Por favor ingrese su nombre";
        $status_nombres = 'False';
    }
    //validando apellidos
    if(!empty($apellidos)) {
        $apellidos = htmlspecialchars($apellidos);
        if(preg_match($patron_texto, $apellidos)) {
            $status_apellidos = 'True';
        } else {
            $mensaje_apellidos = "El apellido sólo puede contener letras y espacios";
            $status_nombres = 'False';
        }
    } else {
        $mensaje_apellidos = "Por favor ingrese su apellido";
        $status_apellidos = 'False';
    }
    //guardando estatus rut
    if(!empty($rut)) {
        $status_rut = 'True';
    }
    //validando telefono
    if(!empty($telefono)) {
        $telefono = htmlspecialchars($telefono);
        if(preg_match($patron_telefono, $telefono)){
            $status_telefono = 'True';
        } else {
            $mensaje_telefono = "El telefono son 9 digitos";
            $status_telefono = 'False';
        }
    } else {
        $mensaje_telefono = "Por favor ingresar un telefono de 9 digitos";
        $status_telefono = 'False';
    }
    //validando email
    if(!empty($email)) {
        if(preg_match($patron_email, $email)){
            $status_email = 'True';
        } else {
            $mensaje_email = "Ingrese correctamente el correo";
            $status_email = 'False';
        }
    } else {
        $mensaje_telefono = "Por favor ingresar correo";
        $status_telefono = 'False';
    }
    //validando la repeticion del correo
    if(!empty($reemail)) {
        if(preg_match($patron_email, $reemail)) {
            if($email == $reemail) {
                $status_reemail = 'True';
            } else {
                $mensaje_reemail = "los correos deben ser identicos";
                $status_reemail = 'False';
            }
        } else {
            $mensaje_reemail = "Ingrese correctamente la repeticion del correo";
            $status_reemail = 'False';
        }
    } else {
        $mensaje_reemail = "Por favor repite tu correo";
        $status_reemail = 'False';
    }

    if(!empty($terminos)) {
        $status_terminos = 'True';
    }
    
}
```
````

y finalmente tenemos la validación del rut por js

```js
function checkRut(rut) {
  // Despejar Puntos
  var valor = rut.value.replace('.', '');
  // Despejar Guión
  valor = valor.replace('-', '');

  // Aislar Cuerpo y Dígito Verificador
  cuerpo = valor.slice(0, -1);
  dv = valor.slice(-1).toUpperCase();

  // Formatear RUN
  rut.value = cuerpo + '-' + dv

  // Si no cumple con el mínimo ej. (n.nnn.nnn)
  if (cuerpo.length < 7) {
    rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Incompleto");
    return false;
  }

  // Calcular Dígito Verificador
  suma = 0;
  multiplo = 2;

  // Para cada dígito del Cuerpo
  for (i = 1; i <= cuerpo.length; i++) {

    // Obtener su Producto con el Múltiplo Correspondiente
    index = multiplo * valor.charAt(cuerpo.length - i);

    // Sumar al Contador General
    suma = suma + index;

    // Consolidar Múltiplo dentro del rango [2,7]
    if (multiplo < 7) {
      multiplo = multiplo + 1;
    } else {
      multiplo = 2;
    }

  }

  // Calcular Dígito Verificador en base al Módulo 11
  dvEsperado = 11 - (suma % 11);

  // Casos Especiales (0 y K)
  dv = (dv == 'K') ? 10 : dv;
  dv = (dv == 0) ? 11 : dv;

  // Validar que el Cuerpo coincide con su Dígito Verificador
  if (dvEsperado != dv) {
    rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Inválido");
    return false;
  }

  // Si todo sale bien, eliminar errores (decretar que es válido)
  rut.setCustomValidity('');
}
```

Por ultimo ahora que tengo todo validado, tengo que enviar la información a mi pagina compra, yo lo hacia con `echo 'compra';` al utilizar url amigables es funcional, pero ahora tiene que ser despues de la validación como lo puedo hacer para enviar estos datos validados a la url que necesito que reciba los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo solucione en ves de seguir con php valide todo por javascript para que todo sea validado y requerido para hacer todo mas simple.

```js
function valNombres(nombres) {

  nombre = nombres.value;
  patron_Nombre = /^([a-zñáéíóú]+[\s]*)+$/;
  if (nombre == null || nombre.length == 0) {
    nombres.setCustomValidity("Complete este campo");
    return false;
  }
  if (!patron_Nombre.test(nombre)) {
    nombres.setCustomValidity("Nombre Invalido");
    return false;
  }

  nombres.setCustomValidity('');
}

function valApellidos(apellidos) {
  apellido = apellidos.value;
  patron_Nombre = /^([a-zñáéíóú]+[\s]*)+$/;
  if (apellido == null || apellido.length == 0) {
    apellidos.setCustomValidity("Complete este campo");
    return false;
  }
  if (!patron_Nombre.test(apellido)) {
    apellidos.setCustomValidity("Apellido Invalido");
    return false;
  }

  apellidos.setCustomValidity('');
}

function valTelefono(telefono) {

  celular = telefono.value;
  patron_Telefono = /^\d{9}$/;
  if (!patron_Telefono.test(celular)) {
    telefono.setCustomValidity("El celular debe tener 9 digitos");
    return false;
  }
  telefono.setCustomValidity('');
}

function valEmail(email) {

  correo = email.value;
  patron_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
  if (!patron_email.test(correo)) {
    email.setCustomValidity("Ingrese un correo valido");
    return false;
  }
  email.setCustomValidity('');

}

function valReemail(reemail) {

  reCorreo = reemail.value;
  if (reCorreo != correo) {
    reemail.setCustomValidity("Deben ser identicos los correos");
    return false;
  }
  reemail.setCustomValidity('');
}
```

de tal manera que ahora solo tengo que agregar en el action un echo 'compra' para la url amigable

```html
<section class="container_form">
  <div class="form">
    <h2>Rellena el formulario para participar</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo 'compra'?>" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label for="nombres">Nombres</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres" id="nombres" required oninput="valNombres(this)" placeholder="Nombres">
        <!--<div class="valid-feedback">Valido.</div>-->

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" required oninput="valApellidos(this)" placeholder="Apellidos">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rut">Rut</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut" id="rut" required oninput="checkRut(this)" placeholder="11111111-1">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefono">Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" required oninput="valTelefono(this)" placeholder="985114418">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required oninput="valEmail(this)" placeholder="example@gmail.com">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reemail">Repetir Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="reemail" class="form-control" name="reemail" id="reemail" required oninput="valReemail(this)" placeholder="example@gmail.com">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="terminos" value="ok" id="customCheck" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck"><a href="">Acepto los términos y condiciones de las bases del concurso.</a> </label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit_compra" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">PAGA AQUÍ</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```